# How much will the variance change in this scenario?

Tags: variance

Imagine that a firm decides to increase the salary of every single of its employees by 10% of their current salary. The average of the salaries will increase by 10% too. But, how will the variance of the salaries change?

Answer (score 0):

The variance will increase by 21%.

We know that **Var[aX] = a2 Var[X]**. 10% increase in the salary of every employee equals when each salary is multiplied by 1.1; and the square of 1.1 is 1.21, which is 21% more than the previous variance.